# How to stop wrap onto the next line if another content is too large

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to display three items in a bootstrap list group.

Here, in the middle, if the content is larger than it is currently making the content on the left overflowed.

[image]

The code i have came up with so far is:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0-9/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">

      <div class="d-flex align-items-end">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300" style="width: 50px;height:50px;object-fit: cover;" />
        <span style="margin-left: -20px;margin-bottom: -8px;" class="font-weight-bold text-warning"><i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i></span>
      </div>

      <div class="ml-2">
        <p class="h3 py-3">
          Dapibus ac facilisis in

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="font-weight-light">05-19-2022 4:20</p>
  </li>


  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">

      <div class="d-flex align-items-end">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?u=a042581f4e29026704e" style="width: 50px;height:50px;object-fit: cover;" />
        <span style="margin-left: -20px;margin-bottom: -8px;" class="font-weight-bold text-warning"><i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i></span>
      </div>

      <div class="ml-2">
        <p class="h3 py-3">
          Nullam semper lorem eget tortor consectetur, id mollis magna scelerisque.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="font-weight-light">05-19-2022 4:20</p>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

How to keep that content as it is without changing its layout when the text content is large?

I wanted to achieve this using the pure bootstrap.

Comment: `<p style="white-space: nowrap" class="font-weight-light">` does the trick, but I think you should use 3 divs instead of 2 divs and a p, for a better structure.

Comment: it is pushing the content to more right, instead of wrapping itself to the next lines.

Answer (score 0):

Please try white-space: nowrap for the font-weight-light class

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add **class="text-nowrap"** in those elements.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0-9/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">

      <div class="d-flex align-items-end">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300" style="width: 50px;height:50px;object-fit: cover;" />
        <span style="margin-left: -20px;margin-bottom: -8px;" class="font-weight-bold text-warning"><i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i></span>
      </div>

      <div class="ml-2">
        <p class="h3 py-3">
          Dapibus ac facilisis in

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="font-weight-light text-nowrap">05-19-2022 4:20</p>
  </li>


  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">

      <div class="d-flex align-items-end">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?u=a042581f4e29026704e" style="width: 50px;height:50px;object-fit: cover;" />
        <span style="margin-left: -20px;margin-bottom: -8px;" class="font-weight-bold text-warning"><i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i></span>
      </div>

      <div class="ml-2">
        <p class="h3 py-3">
          Nullam semper lorem eget tortor consectetur, id mollis magna scelerisque.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="font-weight-light text-nowrap">05-19-2022 4:20</p>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```